# VBA - error when deleting multiple worksheet

Tags: vba

I wrote the VBA code to delete multiple sheets. It can delete as my purpose but i got the error below when it complete the deleting
Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub deletesheet()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'On Error Resume Next
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.name <> "sheet1" Then
                ws.Delete
            End If
    Next ws
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

If I put "On Error Resume Next" it can skip this issue, but i really want to know why it happen this and how to solve it ? Can you please help look ?

[image]

Comment: This is a common problem for new users of VBA.  When you are deleting items from a collection you must delete from the end of the collection, not the start .  As a consequence you cannot use a for each loop.  Instead you must use  a for To loop using thisworkbook.worksheets.count to 1 step -1.

Comment: Usually, this method should work (I tried it out), except for the case where the first worksheet does not really have the exact name "sheet1". Maybe your first worksheet has the name "Sheet1" and not "sheer1"? On localized Excel versions, the sheet name can be different.

Comment: @freeflow: I suspected this as the source of the error when I read the question, but I tried it out and surprisingly, it seems indeed to work in this case.

Comment: @DocBrown yes, my firstsheet named "Sheet1".  mean i need to change name of the first sheet in this case ?

Comment: Is it because he is deleting every single worksheet which is not allowed? (All workbook must have at least 1 worksheet). Just change to `If ws.name <> "Sheet1" Then`. It is case sensitive so you have to match the name exactly the same.

Comment: @RaymondWu my purpose is keep only the sheet named "Sheet1". So i just write this to delete the rest.  do you have any alternative ?

Comment: @thangvc91 just change the line in my previous comment and it will be fine. Your code is currently deleting all worksheets since there isn't a worksheet called "sheet1" (I assume there isn't)

Comment: now just change the name of sheet1 , it could work fine. Thank you all.

Comment: You don't have to change the name of the sheet, you have to change the string in code from "sheet1" to "Sheet1".